# HAProxy - Support of Arithmetical Operations

Tags: acl, haproxy

I am trying to implement a logic as below to route the requests across different backends depending on if some part of the URL is "odd" or "even" number. The logic is described as below:

- Parse the URL and find the Id.
- If Id even number (id%2 == 0) then route the request to "backendX". Else route to "backendY".

***Sample URL: [http://api.example.com/devices/demo-devices/{id}](http://api.example.com/devices/demo-devices/%7Bid%7D)***

Is it possible to implement such a logic as explained above using the ACL's? Or any alternate approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can use lua to extend HAProxy [5 Ways to Extend HAProxy with Lua](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/5-ways-to-extend-haproxy-with-lua/).